# Show <table>s horizontally in a div

Tags: css

am very bad in css stuff :( i couldn't find anyway to do the following :

for example i have a div with fixed width (700px) and i have tables inside of it (100px width each) , how can i order these table elements horizontally in that div ? , like icons in the file explorer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table { display: inline-block; }
```

This should work just fine for you.

Answer (score 2):

You want to order the tables, or the cells in a table? If you want to order the tables themselves, you could float each table left so that they appear side-by-side. However, you'd kind of need to know the number of tables in advance.

Comment: Agreed, except knowing the number of tables in advance. Why?

Comment: I think why need to knowing the number of tables is because if the total width of the tables bigger than the fixed width of the div, some tables will be pushed down.

Comment: Well, I guess it's not really necessary. If you have many tables, I can easily see running into problems from different table heights, how it wraps to the next row, etc. You may be able to get it to work. I guess I'm not really sure if you could do that and have it look good in all cases and on all browsers.

Comment: i want to order the tables in that div that may vary in number